# Shopify's Slate successfully installed, but no commands work. Any solution?

Tags: npm, shopify, shopify-template

I'm following a tutorial about custom Shopify themes. I've created a repo with my theme files. I've created a new project with `npm init`, no problem there.

I've then installed Slate with `npm install @shopify/slate --save`, again without any issues.

However, when I try to run any Slate commands, eg `slate -v` or `slate migrate` I get an error message:

```
-bash: slate: command not found
```

Would anyone know what I could do to fix this?

(ps I also tried `npm install @shopify/slate --save-dev`. My version of npm is 6.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Slate with the global flag `npm install -g @shopify/slate`

If that fails, check your Node version and see if any [issues](https://github.com/Shopify/slate/issues) with your OS/Version

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, it suggests you use either `npx` or `yarn` to install Slate. Try:

```
npx slate-tools build
```

or

```
yarn slate-tools build
```